# "No manifest detected", what am i missing?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, progressive-web-apps, manifest

Hellooo,

I'm trying to build a PWA, but my manifest is not detected.
I put it at the root of my project.

It contains

```
    {
    "name": "MiniSysteme",
    "short_name": "MiniSys",
    "start_url": "/index.php",
    "display": "standalone",
    "background_color": "#FFE9D2",
    "theme_color": "#FFE1C4",
    "orientation": "portrait-primary",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/img/icons/icon-72x72.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "72x72"
        },
        {
            "src": "/img/icons/icon-96x96.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "96x96"
        },
```

and i added this line in the head of my index.php

```
<link rel="manifest" href="../manifest.json" >
```

The page is constructed via MVC structure. The index.php call the viewHeader.php
via *require("view/viewHeader.php");* which contain the link to the manifest file.

Do you think that structure leads to a problem over the fetch manifest system ?

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AbsO.png)

SOLUTION :
The problem was an invisible character between link et rel in the  tag ! Crazy but real. Now the manifest is detected and the tags remain in the . This invisible character or bad space was breaking the head and opening the body.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in the same directory as showing in the structure you should be using,

`<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" >`

Comment: Sorry, I tried "../manifest" because it never works with href="manifest.json". And since my index.php requiere the html in a folver 'view', i tried with "../manifest"

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if it has something to do with the fact my  and  tags appears in  even if i don't have declared them there !

[resulted page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Ti0.png)

[written header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRUF1.png)